# Access Post details posted by application using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently my Facebook application sets default privacy as Friends while posting on Facebook. Is it possible to change default privacy as public OR can I access details of that fb post using graph api even if the privacy is set to friends?

In case of post having privacy set to friends I get the following error:

```
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "HItrveu8gg0"
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the privacy while posting, there is a parameter for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish

But:

> This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the
>   one granted.

If you want to access posts later, authorize the user with the `user_posts` permission.

Comment: so how i can access a post having privacy ALL_FRIENDS using graph api, while allowing access to the app the default privacy settings are set to friends.

Comment: did you authorize the user with user_posts?

Comment: not yet, that would require facebook review so will have to wait for a while.
One more thing confusing me is whether  app token should be used or something else

Comment: You will need `user_posts` permission to access any posts of the user; what privacy setting those posts have doesn’t matter.

Comment: you don´t need review for testing. all permissions work without review for everyone with a role in the app. of course you need user_posts for reading user posts. and of course you need a USER token, an app token does not have any relation to a user.